# How to get sum of count of the columns in oracle

Tags: oracle

How to get sum of columns of Completed,NOBANINSYSTEM,NoEmailtocreateBAN,AccessRestictedToCustomer,MoreAddress,
MoreBANs,DuplicateRecords for my table below.

Query as below

```
SELECT
    SYSTEM AS SYSTEM,
    count(*) as Total_Data_Split,
    COUNT(case when status = 'Order Completed'  then 1 end) AS Completed,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'Mismatch in Name'  then 1 end) AS NOBANINSYSTEM,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'Invalid PoPUP'  then 1 end) AS NoEmailtocreateBAN,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'Discuss'  then 1 end) AS EmailbillBenefit,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'Restricted'  then 1 end) AS AccessRestictedToCustomer,
      COUNT(case when comments='Customer' then 1 end) AS MoreAddress,
    COUNT(case when comments='Exists' then 1 end) AS MoreBANs,
     COUNT(case when comments=' Batch' then 1 end) AS DuplicateRecords,
      COUNT(case when comments=' order.' then 1 end) AS Customer
      FROM Test WHERE BATCH NOT IN ('Test') GROUP BY SYSTEM;
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Please use google or similar to find the instructions for formatting code. You are asking for help from volunteers - the least you can do is to post readable stuff.

Comment: To sum up N columns just write `col1 + col2 + ... + colN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your current query as a source (subquery or CTE, as in my example), and then fetch all its columns plus sum of columns you specified:

```
WITH temp AS
  (SELECT
    SYSTEM AS SYSTEM,
    count(*) as Total_Data_Split,
    COUNT(case when status   = 'Order Completed'  then 1 end) AS Completed,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'Mismatch'  then 1 end) AS NOBANINSYSTEM,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'Invalid'  then 1 end) AS NoEmailtocreateBAN,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'Discuss '  then 1 end) AS EmailbillBenefit,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'Access'  then 1 end) AS AccessRestictedToCustomer,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'Multiple' then 1 end) AS MoreAddress,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'Multiple' then 1 end) AS MoreBANs,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'Multiple Customer entries' then 1 end) AS DuplicateRecords,
    COUNT(case when comments = 'the order.' then 1 end) AS CustomerPrimaryIncomeMiss
   FROM test 
   WHERE BATCH NOT IN ('Test') 
   GROUP BY SYSTEM
  )      
SELECT t.*,
       (  completed
        + nobaninsystem
        + noemailtocreateban
        + accessrestictedtocustomer
        + moreaddress
        + morebans
        + duplicaterecords) AS total
FROM temp t;
```